# Understand cpu and mem SIGAR output

Tags: java, windows, performance-testing

I'm actually using SIGAR in my java project to get performance information of the device while executing a specific function in my program, I am using `getprocmem(pid)` and `getproccpu(pid)` just after the goal function in code.
But I have trouble to understand the output of this two function when I test the example provide with SIGAR API I get this :

Procinfo output:

[image]

My question is, what does that value exactly mean ( ko, Mo ...), and where to add that function exactly in my code to get consumption information of one function in my java class?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags, this has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: i just thought that who develop encryption software uses SIGAR more to test performance , so i made an encryption tag